# How do I remove Facebook notifications in the Chrome Browser

Tags: google-chrome, facebook

As you see the image below, how to stop them from showing?

I have tried all I can to stop them but nothing works. In Facebook settings all notefictions are "off" but I still get this popup. In Chrome Settings also Facebook are not allowed to show notefications

so what is wrong or where do I turn them of?

[image]

Comment: You could try a browser not linked directly to Facebook [Google owns FB] & entirely supported by advertising revenue & user tracking.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `settings` -> `privacy and security` -> `site settings` -> `permissions` / `notifications`

In that section, there is a Block and Allow list.  Either remove facebook from the allow list or add them to the block list.

If you are seeing these notifications only on the facebook page, and not on other pages, then it is not a browser notification, but a feature of facebook itself.  You will need to check your settings within facebook to fix this, assuming facebook allows that flexibility.   Blocking components a website wants to put on its own page would require a browser plugin that edits the web pages before you see them.

Comment: Thanks, I did [that](https://snipboard.io/xcudbY.jpg) and that was the first thing I tried actually. Any other suggestion?

Comment: You could try disabling notifications by default with the first switch on that page.

Comment: The first switch must be on, it say "Websites much ask for permissions to send notifications", I tried and toggled it off. I got a Facebook notifications, I get them even it's on or off.
There got to be some other settings??

Comment: Are you getting the notificaion when you are looking at facebook's page, or on all tabs including ones that are not facebook's?

Comment: I have to be on the Facebook page to see the pop up notification I show in the image, in my OP. They dont show on other tabs, of course it would not make any sense

Comment: Added that case to the question.

Comment: This is so strange, I turn of all settings about notifications in Facebook Settings, all are off but still the popup show

Comment: You could report it as a bug to facebook.  They'll probably laugh at you, because it's all part of their nefarious plan to grab your attention.  :-P

Comment: yea must be right.